# Making C-Excutable/Setup file, that runs on any computer

Tags: c++, c, windows-server-2008

I have a c-project/file named "Project.c",in windows server 8, And i can compile and run on my computer.I use the following command to compile/build.

```
gcc -o myexcutable Project.c external_libraries
```

:-external libraries are,libraries like: `lpthread`,`lpcre` and others...

And run`:$./myexcutable`

but,now, i want to pick my executable(only) to other compute as a "setup". Then when i start my executable/setup, it should run! but it doesn't. My Question is, is there any technique to make executable file that runs on an windows server 8? thanks.

`Edit[1]`:Basically, when i say any "Pc/computer", its a windows server 8(same OS)

`Edit[2]`:The error am getting, says: `The program can't start because cygwin1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

Comment: Assuming any PC includes Linuxes, BSDs, Macs and so on, it is impossible. All of them have a bit different syscalls, different binary loaders and so on. The best you can do is to stick to standard C/C++, compile on each and then distribute specific binaries.

Comment: Do an internet search for `GCC Cross-Compiler` One interesting link could be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler

Comment: @Xarn: thank you for reply pls, but even on the same machine/comuter(win server 8), it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because every architecture works a little differently, it is basically impossible, the best you can do is statically link the libraries and if the other pcs have the same architecture and operating system it should work.
to statically link libraries use the -static option like so:

```
gcc -o myexcutable Project.c -static external_libraries
```

Another solution would be to compile many different versions of the setup and use a different one for each pc.